# Reuse of lazy loaded module in different App

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular-module

I'm developing an enterprise angular 2 application that has many lazy loaded modules. Recently I had to make a new app, an admin panel for the app and I want to reuse one lazy loaded module that I created previously on my main app... I searched on google about it and the only way I found was to break the module to a library and host it on npm so I can install it on my other project. I find this very frustrating because it needs money for private repos etc...

Comment: grab the source code and integrate it directly in your app

Comment: i want to avoid copy-pasting the module because it uses many components from other shared modules and i may need to copy the half code from my project

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 approaches.

### Code lives in different repositories

Then you'll need some way to share the code between the repos. Ideas here could be:

- npm (you could also host npm packages somewhere else than the public npm registry)
- github
- anywhere else where you could host & fetch the common code from

### Code lives in the same repository

If the code lives in the same repo, the code sharing becomes more easy. `angular.json` is even specifically built to accommodate for for such a "mono repo" approach.